# How to validate ember-power-select using jquery validation?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, jquery-validate

I have a power-select that I want to validate. When user presses submit, I want them to have selected from the power-select dropdown. If they have not selected from the dropdown, then it would show a warning. I am using `ember-power-select` for dropdown and `jquery-validation` for validation.

Below is what my ember template (component) has - I included a text input (`amount`) that works:

```
//emblem.js

form id="salesForm"
    .form-group
      label Account Name (Organization)
      = power-select options=organizations selected=sale.organization searchField="name" onchange=(action "organizationChanged" ) placeholder="Account Name" required="required" name="organization" id="organization" as |organization|
        = organization.name

    .form-group
      label Amount
      = input type="text" value=sale.amount placeholder="Amount" class="form-control" required="required" name="amount" id="amount"
    ...
```

Inside my component.js:

```
  didRender(){
    ...
    var validator = this.$('#salesForm').validate({
      rules: {
        organization: {
          required: true
        },
        amount: {
          required: true
        }
      },
      messages: {
        organization: {
          required: "Please select an organization"
        },
        amount: {
          required: 'Please enter amount number'
        }
      },
      errorPlacement: function(error, element){
        error.insertAfter(element);
      }
    });
    ...
  }
```

Currently, if I don't select anything, it shows error under `amount`, but it does not show anything under `organization`. I noticed that when I inspected power-select, it has a fixed power-select id. Both my `required='required' and`name='organization` lines were not shown either.

[image: ember-power-select-inspect]

**Code:**

```
<div aria-haspopup="true" class="ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-power-select-trigger" id="ember-power-select-trigger-ember1017" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="true" aria-pressed="true" aria-controls="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember1026">
    <span class="ember-power-select-placeholder">Account Name</span>
<span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
</div>
```

Compare that with `Amount`, where it has the specified `name, id, and required`. I think this is the reason why, but I am not 100% sure.

[image: amount input text inspect]

**Code:**

```
<input id="amount" placeholder="Amount" required="" name="amount" type="text" class="form-control ember-view ember-text-field error" aria-required="true">
```

In short, how can I enable basic validation on ember-power-select so it shows error message when user does not select from dropdown?

Comment: Please do not show pictures or images of code.  Please take the time to copy/paste or type it out.

Comment: Your root problem is that your `select` does not contain a `name` attribute... focus on this.  I also can't tell for sure, because I'm looking at a tiny blurry picture, but it seems that your select is not even a `select` element... this too will be a big problem for jQuery Validate.

Comment: Bottom line:  you'll have to inspect your live DOM and show us the actual rendered code... only this rendered code is used by JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @Sparky! Thanks for the comment. I edited my post and added the code. 
On your second comment, when you said my select is not even a `select` element, what is it that jquery-validation require about having a select element to make it work?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: If you have something that says `placeholder`, then you are not showing the live code as rendered in the DOM.  Yes, the jQuery Validate plugin can only validate `select`, `textarea`, certain `contenteditable` elements, and certain `input` elements.   As long as you have a `select` with a unique `name` and the first `option` contains `value=""`, then it will validate.